# How can the following block scheme be made?

Tags: algorithms, block

My university is asking for a specification of an algorithm and provided this block scheme as an example. I an not very good at latex so I googled how to do this with tikz, but did not found something useful.

[image: 1]

Comment: It can be done with `nicematrix` package or in plain Ti*k*z, for example. Maybe with a table and some improvements. What did you try already? Please come back with a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) code.